# RegEx to Remove GTM Param

Tags: jquery, regex

What would be the regex to replace the entire string of ?_ga= and the random cookie with "" empty string so the result would be www.example.com instead of example.com/?_ga=1.263876746.721545158.1431088909

This example only targets the ?_ga= and is only a demo to simulate the issue:

```js
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        $(this).attr("href", "?_ga=1.263876746.721545158.1431088909"); 
      var value = $(this).attr('href');
      $(this).attr('href', value.replace('?_ga=', ''));
        e.preventDefault();
            alert(this);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com/">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/">Link 2</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aj948wv4/

Comment: You trying to replace all `?_ga=1.263876746.721545158.1431088909` by blank ?

Comment: yes. ?_ga= + the cookie you see with empty string. the cookie always random

Comment: In cases like this, the question should include several real-life input samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex

`\?_ga=.*`

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB9cU2/1)

Answer (score 0):

This solution better met my needs than the regex

```
    var value = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', value.split('?_ga=')[0]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aj948wv4/2/